# What is the degree of a vector bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

I heard that the degree of a vector bundle encodes the number of "twists" of the bundle.

I heard also that it is roughly the difference between number of roots and number of poles of a  function in a local ring.

Which one is true? I couldn't find any reference to that in Hartshorne or in the Vakil.

Thank you for any help/hints.

Comment: Degree of a vector bundle makes sense only with respect to an (ample) line bundle.  If $L$ is such an ample line bundle, and $E$ is a rank $r$ vector bundle on a projective variety, the degree is defined as the intersection product of $\wedge^r E$ and $L^{\dim X-1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mohan,  I appreciate if you can give me any reference on the subject, as I am even unaware of the intersection product of vector bundles

Comment: How about https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AYQ ?